# logback on a mac returns question marks instead of words

Tags: java, macos, logging, glassfish, logback

I'm just start using logback for logging my Java project running on glassfish3 AS, and I'm noticing some strange thing. This string of code

```
LOG.error("Вычисление {} уже произведено.", calc);
```

generates normal expected output if I'm running my application on windows. But if I'm the same configuration on Mac, I'm having question marks instead of words, like so:

```
15:37:29.083 ERROR r.g.g.c.TotalNachController - ?????????? [id=8871] ??? ???????????.
```

my logback configuration is:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>../logs/logback.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Could someone please tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's your locale on both? How are you viewing the file? Etc.

Comment: on Windows it's ru-Ru. On Mac its en-Us. I'm viewing file via Terminal, textEdit and Sublime Text 2.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you manage to resolve that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to define charset for encoder:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>../logs/logback.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Sadly it's not described in documentation, but you can always lookup properties in source code. Specyfing **<encoder>** instantize PatternLayoutEncoder. Going up to its parent **LayoutWrappingEncoder** you can find method **setCharset()**. When specified it is used, as you can see in http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/encoder/LayoutWrappingEncoder.html#120

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the used text editor is supporting your character set. Also the used terminal may affect the displayed characters also.

I suggest using `more` or `less` UNIX commands from `Terminal` application, that should support your charset, to validate if the characters are printed ok.

Comment: It's neither textEditor nor Terminal problem, as I can see. My Terminal have no problems viewing this string if it's shown by log4j for example. Same with textEditor, I'm using Sublime Text 2 that supports multiple text encodings, but all of them showing question marks.