# Spring Boot : Non English Charecters in log file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encoding

I am using logback.xml for Springboot application logging.
My issue is when there are non-English characters it prints ? in the log file.

I goggle it and found `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

In .conf file i made below entry but still log file is showing ? for non english charecters. I am using Spring boot 2.5.0 version on Linux.

> JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx5024M
>
> RUN_ARGS="-Dspring.config.location=/AGNITY/aconyx/KWD/application.properties
> -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

Comment: Check this post, perhaps it can be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353762/4373948

Comment: @TinyOS : Great. It worked !! Thanks